# How to add a custom javascript to theme in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, javascript, custom, requirejs

I have experience with **Magento 1**, and there adding a custom javascript file was very straightforward and logical.

But when it comes to **Magento 2**, I can't figure out how to add a new js file, where I would put little code snippets that affect different places around the page.

**For example,** I want to modify **'last viewed items'** block on the home page, and use jQuery there and then maybe another script that changes some CSS dynamically somewhere (for example).

I find it very comfortable to do it in one single file like I used to do in Magento 1. Also, Magento official docs didn't help me since it didn't provide information clear enough.. **I guess it has something to do with requireJS but is there another way?** If not then can someone explain it a little clearer than Magento official docs did?

**PS. Tried adding my custom.js file to head block trough XML, but then I didn't get access to jQuery.**

Thanks!

Comment: have you create your custom theme?

Comment: See my detailed answer. I've added you example JS, because this MIGHT cause your problem as well. Always know if you need to use `require` or `define` in JS, since require-js handles things differently.

Comment: I updated the JS in my answer. Please note it, since there was something wrongful in it. Cheers!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**jQuery is already pre-packaged with Magento2, there is no need to implement it on your own, however, you have to utilize it.**

To add JS to your theme you have several possibilities.

By utilizing `default_head_blocks.xml` in `app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Theme/layout/`:

Example Content:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <!-- Add local resources -->
        <css src="css/my-styles.css"/>

        <!-- The following two ways to add local JavaScript files are equal -->
        <script src="Magento_Catalog::js/sample1.js"/>
        <link src="js/sample.js"/>

        <!-- Add external resources -->
    <css src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" src_type="url" />
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js" src_type="url" />
        <link src="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" src_type="url" /> 
    </head>
</page>
```

If you inject JS this way, dont forget to wrap your JS into the `requirejs`-conform way:

```
require(['jquery'], function($){ /* Code... */ })
```

Or: by utilizing `requirejs-config.js` in your themes root folder.

Simply add Deps to it, example:

```
var config = {

    deps: [
        "js/main",
    ],

    map: {
        '*': {
            'owlcarousel': 'js/owl.carousel.min',
            'sticky' : 'js/jquery.sticky',
            'tether' : 'js/tether.min',
            'bootstrap': 'js/bootstrap.min'

        }
    },
    "shim": {
        "owlcarousel": ["jquery"],
        "tether": ["jquery"],
        "bootstrap": ["jquery"]
    }
};
```

In aboves example I register `main.js` by calling it in the Deps. The path is without the `.js` extention, requirejs is handeling this on its own.

Your `main.js` should be located at `web/js/` in your theme.

The content of `main.js` should be like this:

```
define([
  "jquery",
  "whatever lib you wanna use..."
], 
function($) {
  "use strict";

    $(document).ready(function($){
        console.log("DID IT! jQuery log complete.");
    });
    return;
});
```

Comment: I have tried the first option, but then when I tried to use jQuery on sample.js(in your case), it didnt work. It gave error which said something like "$ (or jQuery) is not defined". Will try the second option soon. But for now I copied theme.js from Magento Blank theme to my own theme, and by surprise it worked like that. I can even use jQuery that way. (My theme inherits from Magento Blank)

Comment: if jQuery is not defined you need to wrap your code in `require(['jquery'], function($){ /* your code... */ });` - hope it helps.

Comment: I've updated the answer again for better understanding! Glad that I could helped you.

Comment: @Max I tried your method ( https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/206124/how-to-use-2-third-party-jquery-plugins-in-one-custom-module-magento-2/206136#206136) i posted a question , can you please check.

Comment: You need to add the `sample1.js`inside the `requirejs-config.js` map object otherwise you get errors. Also after clear all your cache!                                   
`php bin/magento cache:clean`
`php bin/magento cache:flush`
`php bin/magento setup:upgrade`
`php bin/magento setup:di:compile`

Comment: I think it should be <link src="Vendor_Module::js/sample.js"/> not <link src="js/sample.js"/>

Answer (score 4):

Please put JS in web/js folder in app/design/frontend/vendorname/themename and call into Magneto_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml file..

```
<script src="jquery.js" />
<script src="js/modernizr.js" />
```

and Create one requirejs-config.js in the Magento_Theme.

```
var config = {
map: {
    '*': {




        modernizer        : 'Magento_Theme/js/modernizr.js'}




    }
};
```

Then remove pub/static folder expect .htaccess file and remove cache and run it..

Comment: is it usefulr for u?

Comment: i think we should remove js from the end of the file

Comment: @MoinMalek Any help thanks https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/321141/57334