# Magento2 - Add custom javascript to 'My Account' page

Tags: magento2, module, magento2.3, configuration

I've been trying to find questions, articles, or documentation covering this, but haven't been able to find what I need or haven't understood it yet.

I have a custom module that a colleague wrote (who has since left) that adds some functionality via an API endpoint that we consume in a different application.

I now need to add some javascript to the `/customer/account/` page.

I've read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3938134/1739852) and understand that I need to put something like the below into a config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<layout version="0.1.0">
    <customer_account_view>
         <reference name="head">
                <action method="addJs"><script>{my script}.js</script></action>
            </reference>
    </customer_account_view>
</layout>
```

Where does `{my script}.js` need to live inside my module directory, and which config file do I need to put the above block (if it is correct) inside my etc directory?

The current module directory looks like this:

[image: Add to cart directory]

**UPDATE**

The namespace for my module is James and the module is called AddToCart (i.e `app/code/James/AddToCart`.
Following the advice inside solution 2 by @xanka, I first created the `customer_account_index.xml` file at the following location `app/code/James/AddToCart/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_index.xml` with the following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <script src="james_addtocart::postMessage.js"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

I then created the script inside the `app/code/James/AddToCart/view/frontend/web/js/postMessage.js` file:

```
console.log('test');
```

I then ran the following commands, unsure if necessary:

```
php bin/magento maintenance:enable
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php -d memory_limit=2G bin/magento setup:di:compile
php -d memory_limit=8G -d max_execution_time=18000 bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento maintenance:disable
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
redis-cli -p 6379 flushall
```

Everything ran successfully, however I cannot see 'test' in my dev console when I log in and visit `/customer/account` and when I view source, I cannot see that my script is included in the head. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: The reference you are following is for Magento 1. With Magento 2 the approach is different. Please refer : https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/custom_js.html and https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/156144/2443

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope you doing well!
To way right there.
1: in your theme create new layout file in
`<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
    <script src="Magento_Customer::your_custom.js"/>
    </head>
</page>`

> app/code/design/frontend/{theme_theme}/Customer/layout/customer_account_index.xml.

push your js file in your current theme like:

> app/code/design/frontend/{theme_theme}/Customer/web/js/your_custom.js

2: You can create new module and push you code like

> app/code/namespace/module_name/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_index.xml.

`<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
    <script src="namespace_modulename::your_custom.js"/>
    </head>
</page>`

Then create new {your_custom.is} in

> app/code/namespace/module_name/view/frontend/web/js/{your_custom.js}

Comment: My current extension is not a theme. Can I do it from the existing extension inside `app/code` or do I have to create a theme to do this?

Comment: Sorry I see you mention how to do it from my existing extension on option 2. I will try that!

Comment: I tried option 2, and whilst I get no errors, I don't see my script running. See my updated question for steps followed. I'd really appreciate it if you could see where I have gone wrong.

Comment: I have posted a new question to address the problems I am having with this not working; https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/305336/custom-javascript-not-running-from-module

Comment: Hi @James, I answer the question pls check