# Custom javascript not running from module

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, frontend, configuration

I have a Magento module that currently provides a custom API route. I am wanting to update it to push some Javascript to the `/customer/account` page.

I tried following the answer [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/305224/58301) but this didn't work, my script is not rendered or executed on the customer account page.

My module looks like this:

[image: module directory]

My module lives in `app/Code/James/AddToCart`.

I have a `app/code/James/AddToCart/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_index.xml` file that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
    <script src="james_addtocart::postMessage.js"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

I then have the Javascript file living in `app/code/James/AddToCart/view/frontend/web/js/postMessage.js` and it looks like this:

```
console.log('test');
alert('I am working');
```

The real script I will use is not the above, however it is all just vanilla javascript with no dependencies.

I then ran these commands (not sure if necessary):

```
php bin/magento maintenance:enable
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php -d memory_limit=2G bin/magento setup:di:compile
history
php -d memory_limit=8G -d max_execution_time=18000 bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento maintenance:disable
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
redis-cli -p 6379 flushall
```

However when I go to the /customer/account page, I do not see my script run at all.

What am I doing wrong?

**Update**

As per @xanka's comment, I have updated my `customer_account_index.xml` file to be:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
    <script src="James_AddToCart::postMessage.js"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

However this still isn't running the alert nor the console.log statement.

**Update 2**

I have added the `postMessage.js` file to `app/code/James/AddToCart/view/frontend/web/postMessage.js` and then added a new `app/code/James/AddToCart/view/frontend/layout/customer_account.xml` with the following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
    <link src="James_AddToCart::postMessage.js"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

I now have a `postMessage.js` file in `app/code/James/AddToCart/view/frontend/web/postMessage.js` and `app/code/James/AddToCart/view/frontend/web/js/postMessage.js` that looks like this:

```
require(["jquery"],
    function($){

    console.log('test');
    alert('I am working');

})
```

When I visit the `/customer/account` page, I do not see an alert or the console.log statement in my dev tools.

Comment: in your customer_account_index.xml module should is `James_AddToCart::postMessage.js`.

Comment: @xanka I have made this change, but when visiting the `/customer/account` page I do not get the alert nor the console log in my dev tools. I have updated the `customer_account_index.xml` with what you say (now included in question). Is there something more I need to do?

Comment: Share you js file path

Comment: please try this way on your customer_account_index.xml
`<link src="James_AddToCart::js/postMessage.js"/>`

Comment: @Ranganathan as per my question, the Javascript (relative to the root Magento directory) is app/code/James/AddToCart/view/frontend/web/js/postMessage.js

Comment: so can you let me know what exact error are you facing?

Comment: @sarveshDineshkumarPatel the Javascript in my `postMessage.js` file is not running on the `/customer/account` page. I do not see an alert, not do i see the console.log statement run in my dev tools.

Comment: ok Let me check it now

Comment: can you tell me your vendor name and module name please

Comment: @sarveshDineshkumarPatel vendor name is `James` and module name is `AddToCart`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104911/discussion-between-sarvesh-dineshkumar-patel-and-james).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this into your file

**app/code/James/AddToCart/view/frontend/layout/customer_account.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
    <script src="James_AddToCart::postMessage.js"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

**app/code/James/AddToCart/view/frontend/web/js/postMessage.js**

```
require(["jquery"],
    function($){

    console.log('test');
    alert('I am working');

})
```

run magento command

```
php  bin/magento s:up

php bin/magento s:s:d -f

php bin/magento c:c
```

Comment: I have made this change, yet it still does not work.

Comment: Please see my updated question with the changes I have made.

Comment: check answer is update

Comment: There was a caching issue, even with the cache:clear command (from opcache - whoops :)!). However, even once resolved, I needed to add the `require(['jquery']...` part. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the file with the name `customer_account.xml` and need to add code like this one.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" label="Customer My Account (All Pages)" design_abstraction="custom">
    <head>
            <link src="James_AddToCart::postMessage.js"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

Remember your js file is need to put into the following location.

> app\code\James\AddToCart\view\frontend\web\postMessage.js

Comment: I have done this, but it still does not work. I have updated the question with what I have done.

Comment: I update, the naswer kindly check ayou have do same things and run all the commands like upgrade and deploy.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the follow code and try ok.
Update file customer_account_index.xml  or where you want to load choose that xml file and put script on head ok.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
    <script src="James_AddToCart::js/postMessage.js" />
    </head>
</page>
```

and please do cache clear after this.
Hope it works!

Comment: @james please check updated answer.