# Magento 2 - How to add custom JS file path into CMS Block

Tags: javascript, blocks, requirejs, magento2.3.4

How to get JS file in the blocks,

How to declare like:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    src="{{skin url=''}}js/my_custom.js">
</script>
```

My JS path:

```
app/design/frontend/Codazon/fastest/grocery_gourmet/web/js/my_custom.js
```

OR Recommended way to declare JS.

Comment: Do you want to add js on page?

Comment: Yes, In block I just created slider , I want add js for this slider.

Comment: I just pasted my JS to app/design/frontend/Codazon/fastest/grocery_gourmet/web/js/my_custom.js How to get JS path in block.

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 2, you need to add and declare your js file via **RequireJS**

So:

**app/design/frontend/Codazon/fastest/requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            myscript: 'js/my_custom'
        }
    }
};
```

**app/design/frontend/Codazon/fastest/web/js/my_custom.js**

```
define(['jquery'], function($){
   "use strict";
       return function myscript()
       {
           alert("Yes, it woooorks!");
       }
});
```

**app/design/frontend/Codazon/fastest/Magento_Theme/templates/{yourfile}.phtml**

```
    <script>
        require(['jquery', 'myscript'], function($, myscript) {
            myscript();
        });
    </script>
```

**PS** you also need to:

- clean the cache => `php bin/magento c:c`
- clean `var/view_preprocessed` content => `rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/*`
- clean `pub/static` content => `rm -rf pub/static/*`
- deploy the static content = `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

Good luck!

Comment: and how to set js path inside the block.

Comment: In Magento 1 inside the block declared like this => <script type="text/javascript" src="{{skin url=''}}js/my_custom.js"></script>

Comment: Which block ? can you share the path of that block ?

Comment: Block => https://snipboard.io/7ZY2wm.jpg and i want add js path => https://snipboard.io/HsEUVY.jpg

Comment: Ah, you mean a CMS Block, I have never used this way to put the js file directly in the `cms block` to avoid the terrible errors of `requirejs`, I advise you rather to follow my solution then to call the `phtml` rather than the `js`something like : `{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="customblock1" template="yourfile.phtml"}}`you need probably to change the block class

Comment: I want to include the jquery library in my cms blocks, how to declare? In magento 1 declare like <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script> How to do in magento 2 cms block?