# Where to add custom CSS and Js file in freely available custom theme (Appreal Theme from Hiddentechies)

Tags: custom, js-css

I am using **Hiddentechies Appreal free Theme** for my Magento2 project. I want to add a custom CSS file and Js file (for jQuery) so that it will override the classes(CSS file) and add functionality (Js file) which I will include in those files. But I am not sure where to add those files. I have read that we should not touch the vendor folder. So where I should include my custom files. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: For javascript /app/design/frontend/{{themevendor}}/{{themename}}/web/js/ js.js

and For css /app/design/frontend/{themevendor}}/{{themename}}//web/css/css.css

Comment: and after you should add it to body from layut.

/app/design/frontend/{{vendor}}/{{themename}}/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml file

Comment: Thanks @S.P, is it required to make changes in requirejs-config.js file? Thanks

Comment: No for css you not need to add

Comment: But for Js, I need right?? Thanks @S.P

Comment: If you want to add for all pages via layout.
default_head_block.xml layout file

<head>        
        <css src="css/child_custom.css" />                
         <script src="js/enapy_custom.js" />
    </head>

Comment: vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml file would help you

Comment: You can get details for javascript from this reference

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/156144/46039

Comment: check below answer if it will be helpful to you someway.

Answer (score 0):

for add custom css to custom theme. you need to update `default_head_blocks`

You can get Reference from default magento blank theme.

```
vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml
```

Add same way in your custom theme

`vendor/{{magento}}/{{themename}}/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml`

and add style.css file in web folder

```
app/design/frontend/{{themevendor}}/{{themename}}/web/css/custom.css
```

**For add custom js file.**

There are many ways to add js in your theme.

By utilizing `default_head_blocks.xml` in `app/design/frontend/{{theme-Vendor}}/{{theme-name}}/Magento_Theme/layout/`:

Example Content:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>            
        <css src="css/custom.css"/>
        <script src="Magento_Catalog::js/sample1.js"/>
        <link src="js/sample.js"/>                      
        <css src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" src_type="url" />
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js" src_type="url" />
        <link src="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" src_type="url" /> 
    </head>
</page>
```

With **requirejs-config.js** in themes root folder.

example:

```
 var config = {     
        map: {
            '*': {
                'owlcarousel': 'js/owl.carousel.min'
            }
        }
    };
```

The use js in your phtml file.

```
define([
  "jquery",
  "owlcarousel"
], 
function($ , owl) {
  "use strict";

    $(document).ready(function($){
    
    });
    return;
});
```

for more details [refernce](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/156035/how-to-add-a-custom-javascript-to-theme-in-magento-2)