# Magento 2 Uncaught Error: Script error for "popper.js", needed by: jquery.bootstrap

Tags: magento2.4, 404, magento2.4.5p1, pub, bootstrap4

We are using Magento 2.4.5-p1

We add popper.js via a custom module but in the browser console, it is still showing -

```
GET `http://127.0.0.1/xyz/pub/popper.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`
```

Does anyone face this type of issue?

Answer (score 0):

How you added the popper.js  it looks wrong. There are many ways to add js in Magento 2.
The easy one is in `default_head_blocks.xml` layout xml in `app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Theme/layout/`

```
  <!-- The following two ways to add local JavaScript files are equal -->
        <script src="Magento_Catalog::js/sample1.js"/>
        <link src="js/sample.js"/>
```

Here is a similar question [How to add a custom javascript to theme in Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/156035/how-to-add-a-custom-javascript-to-theme-in-magento-2).

Comment: I tried this also but it is not working.

Comment: try adding it with cdn

Comment: Also, try with CDN still showing - GET http://127.0.0.1/xyz/pub/popper.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Comment: When you added the popper.js with CDN, remove the one you added to get it localy. Somewhere it is configured to also get it from local files.